# React App not connectiong to local server

Tags: reactjs, express

I have my local express server running at port 3000, when I `npm start` my react app, it asks to `Would you like to run the app on another port instead? Yes` but takes forever and doesn't take me anywhere.
I tried to set port of my react app in package.json but then it's not responding to the server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: need to see your server code. You probably started something else on that port so you need to pass a port to the start function.

Comment: ```"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",``` change your start script to this with your desired port, this works for me

Comment: @Joe Lloyd My express server is responding to POSTMAN requests at port 3000 so i don't think something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your React app port in your package.json scripts:

replace your script

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

with

```
"start": "set PORT=8080 && react-scripts start"
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you have PORT in your env set it there

Should work with a different port value to stop conflicts.

Make sure your port can be specified with this line

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

then set something in your env

```
PORT=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your port like this in your `package.json` file

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
    },
```

If you are using a `.env` file, I suggest you use @Joe Lloyd his answer. If not, my answer should do the trick.